# Why is 歪形 read as いがみなり?

Tags: readings

I saw the word **歪形** written in a food blog and was surprised to learn that the reading is **いがみなり** ([Weblio Definition](https://www.weblio.jp/content/%E6%AD%AA%E5%BD%A2)). If this were a standard case of *jukujikun*, I think it would be read differently. And it is definitely not standard *ateji* either since the meanings of the kanji are clearly being employed. The いがみ part seems to resemble ゆがみ and also has the い of いびつ - is it possible that it is some kind of hybrid of these two readings? Is なり sometimes used as a type of glossary reading of the kanji 形？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those just happen to be one reading of each of those characters.  From my dictionary (using **Gjiten** with **edict** in Linux)

> - [歪]{いが}む　→　to warp; to swerve; to deflect; to be crooked; to be distorted; to be bent; to incline; to slant; to be perverted; to be gross-grained; to get bent; to be strained;
>
>   - [歪]{いが}み　→　(n) strain; distortion; deformation; bend;
> - [形]{なり}　→　(n,adj-no) (uk) style; way; shape; form; appearance; state;

So it's not a 熟字訓; just two 訓読みs together.

Comment: I see. I was using 三省堂 スーパー大辞林 and it gave 啀む for いがむ. But I can see it listed as 歪む in some other sources now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might be aware of Japanese indigenous language (和語 wago) before Chinese words were imported.

Imported Chinese characters having same/similar meaning were applied to Wago but still being pronounced as the way it was. It is said kun-yomi.
While on-yomi is as you know well.

Wago "いがむ" and "ゆがむ" are phonetic variations, while "いびつ" has worse connotation of being incomplete, so that, I believe they would be reluctant to use いびつ at formal occasions such as dining gatherings.

Wago "なり" means 形. Like in idiom of なりふり構わず, なり is 形 and ふり is 振 or 挙動 in modern Japanese.

So, wago いがみなり means 歪んだ形 and it can be written as 歪形. 
But I believe very few Japanese people can read it いがみなり, when they encounter 歪形 on a paper or monitor screen. Very possibly they will read it as わいけい, and I feel nobody can blame them because wago いがみなり is not a general vocabulary for modern Japanese life.

いがみなり is an archaic word and modern Japanese people will use 歪んだ形 for expressing same matter.